# jspm bundle (CLI): minify source, but don't generate sourceMaps

Tags: systemjs, jspm

I'm using the jspm CLI to create a minified bundle of some files of mine:

```
jspm bundle "app/includeTemplates.js" "app/templates.bundle.js" --minify
```

While this works perfectly fine, I'd also like to specify that **no sourceMaps** should be generated.

How can I specify this via the CLI? My version of jspm is 0.16.39.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the flag is called: **`--skip-source-maps`**

So the following command does the job:

```
jspm bundle "app/includeTemplates.js" "app/templates.bundle.js" --minify --skip-source-maps
```